# How to create index for select query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a query as below, and need to create a index for the XYZ field, can we create index in the select statement:

```
SELECT ABC,
CASE
WHEN B IS NULL AND C IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(C,'/',D)
WHEN B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NULL THEN CONCAT(B,'/',D)
WHEN C IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(B,'/',C,'/',D)
ELSE -1
END AS XYZ,
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE ABC=123
```

Since this XYZ  field is not available in 'from table', we unable to create index as usual in create table.
Please help with this.

Thanks

Comment: What use is an index on a query result? Is this a part of another query?

Comment: Create an index by `(ABC)` or by `(ABC, B, C, D)`. *Since this XYZ field is not available in 'from table', we unable to create index as usual in create table.* You do NOT need by such index. Or you may add generated column using shown expression and index it.

Comment: `.. WHEN C IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL ..` What's the reason for to check the column twice?

Comment: Your CASE can be replaced with simple `CONCAT_WS('/', B, C, D)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could alter your table definition to include `XYZ` as a generated computed column.  Then, add an index on that computed column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN XYZ VARCHAR(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS
CASE
    WHEN B IS NULL AND C IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(C, '/', D)
    WHEN B IS NOT NULL AND C IS NULL THEN CONCAT(B, '/', D)
    WHEN C IS NOT NULL AND C IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(B, '/', C, '/', D)
    ELSE '-1' END
STORED;

CREATE INDEX idx_xyz ON TABLE_NAME (XYZ);
```

Comment: I doubt if that index will help the query.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one looks at the `WHERE` clause first to decide on an `INDEX`.  In this case, `INDEX(ABC)` is very likely to be helpful.